# Parse json data using JSON.net lib

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

How do I parse the following json data using JSON.net lib

```
    Root: {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "query1",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "thread_id": "1920370693067",
          "updated_time": 1340656102,
          "subject": "",
          "snippet": "Test",
          "snippet_author": 100002153560476
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "query2",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "uid": 100002153560476,
          "name": "Santosh Singh"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
    Type: Property
```

I tried following code,but not able to get data

```
JObject j = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
JArray data = (JArray)j["data"];

if (data != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in data[1]["fql_result_set"].Values())
            {

                string innerText = item["name"].ToString();

                string str2 = item["uid"].ToString();
                dictionary[str2] = innerText;
            }
            foreach (var item in data[0]["fql_result_set"].Values().AsJEnumerable())
            {
                FacebookMessage message;
                message.threadId = item["thread_id"].ToString();
                message.updatedTime = item["updated_time"].ToString();
                message.subject = item["subject"].ToString();
                message.snippet = item["snippet"].ToString();
                message.snippetAuthorId = item["snippet_author"].ToString();
                message.snippetAuthorName = dictionary[message.snippetAuthorId];
                allMessages.Add(message);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your json string is not complete. I tried to convert it to a valid one as:

```
{
    "Root": {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "query1",
                "fql_result_set": [
                    {
                        "thread_id": "1920370693067",
                        "updated_time": 1340656102,
                        "subject": "",
                        "snippet": "Test",
                        "snippet_author": 100002153560476
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "query2",
                "fql_result_set": [
                    {
                        "uid": 100002153560476,
                        "name": "Santosh Singh"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

And parsed as:

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach(var data in dynObj.Root.data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}",data.name);
    foreach(var fql in data.fql_result_set)
    {
        foreach (JProperty keyValue in fql)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0} : {1}", keyValue.Name,keyValue.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting null refrence exception on line foreach(var data in dynObj.Root.data)

Comment: @geek I showed you the json I tried to parse. The json string you posted is invalid. What does `Type: Property` mean for example? Where is the first `{` ? . Check your json string.